# How to check passwords match in vanilla Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and I'd like to check if passwords are matched. 
If they do not match,  after the user leaves the confirmation field, the error text `Passwords don't match!` should appear. 
I've seen a couple of solutions which involve using plugins, but I'm wondering what is the idiomatic way to do it using pure vue.js?

https://jsfiddle.net/Babrz/L2md63j7/3/

```
<div id="app">
          <form >
          <div class="form-group">            
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">            
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" v-model="password" placeholder="Password">
          </div> 
          <br>

         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" v-model="password2" placeholder="Confirm Passwrd">
          </div>
          <small v-if="showError">Passwords don't match!</small>
          <br>

          <div class="form-group">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">            
          </div>         

           <br>

          <button type="submit" class="btn login-btn">Register</button>
        </form>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    password2: '',
    age: 0,
    showError: false    
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: When do you want to show the user this information? When they submit the form? Or in real-time as they type? For the first, I'd use a `@submit` on the form that validates and alerts the user if there are issues. For the second, a computed property like `passwordsMatch: function() { return this.password == this.password2; }` and a `v-if="!passwordsMatch"` somewhere to display an error.

Comment: Well, I want the message to appear just after user leaves the `password2` and gets to the next field. I don't want to bother them while they are typing, nor wait until the form is submitted.

Comment: @ceejayoz you should make this comment an answer and add a `focus` test in the computed property ;)

Comment: @Babr You could make your `computed` property check that *something* is in both fields, if you like.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want to use an **onblur** event to run a **validation** on the two password values.  A very basic implementation might look like this.

```
...

<input  v-on:blur="validate" type="password" class="form-control" v-model="password2" placeholder="Confirm Passwrd">
...

...
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    password2: '',
    age: 0,
    showError: false
      
    

  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    },
    validate: function() {
        console.log(this.password === this.password2)
    }
  }
})
...
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

You can get a lot of help if you use something like validate.js to validate your passwords too.

http://validatejs.org

Comment: It should be `this.password == this.password2` . Please correct, and I'll accept.

Comment: its generally not good practice to use the double-equal operator and I'm pretty sure you want to validate on the value of those inputs.